# Initialize var value to null for strongly typed

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something like the following:

I am not sure how to initialize teh restultCLList as I cannot set it to null.

```
    var resultCLlist = null;

    if (RdoStatus.SelectedValue == "Incomplete")
    {
         resultCLList = (from ms in db.ver_ServiceReport
                            join gc in db.map_Sit 
                            on ms.SiteId equals gc.SiteID
                            where gc.CompanyId == companyId
                            select new ServiceReport
                            {
                                VerificationId = ms.VerificationId,
                                SiteId = ms.SiteId,

                            }
                         ).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
         resultCLList = (from ms in db.ver_ServiceReport
                            join gc in db.map_Sites
                            on ms.SiteId equals gc.SiteID
                            where gc.CompanyId == companyId
                            select new ServiceReport
                            {
                                VerificationId = ms.VerificationId,
                                SiteId = ms.SiteId,
                                SiteName = gc.SiteName,
                                TimeStamp = ms.TimeStamp,
                                EntryDate = ms.EntryDate,
                                Supplier = ms.Supplier
                            }
                        ).ToList();

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are coming from the javascript world. C# is strongly typed, unlike javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you use `List<ServiceReport>` instead of `var` ?

You can't initialize `var` to a `null` value, because *null* is not a type itself.You can cast it to `object` but it won't be safe.`var` is useful if you don't know the returning type of the expression on the right side, or if the type name is too long.In this case you know the type, so simply don't use `var`.